# Angular Js + UI router, more than one module each with each owns ui routes config - how?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-module

I have a main app on my application, called "bionico", this app utilizes UI-router
It has it's own $stateProvider configurations! 
And that's fine, it works

BUT I needed to create a new module (cuz I'm trying to insert a step-by-step form on my application, you can find the code here: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router)

To make this step-by-step form I need to create a new module with it's own $stateProvider configurations, the thing is that it doesn't work, I have included this module called "bionico.formApp" in my main app like this:

```
angular.module('bionico', ['ui.router', other modules, 'bionico.formApp'])
```

And that works fine, if I try to use a controller inside "bionico.formApp" it will also work fine. This is the code for this module:

```
// create our angular app and inject ngAnimate and ui-router 
//         =============================================================================
angular.module('bionico.formApp', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', ])

// configuring our routes 
// =============================================================================
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

    .state('form', {
        url: '/form',
        templateUrl: 'templates/campaignForm/form.html',
        controller: 'formCtrl'
    })

     // nested states 
    // each of these sections will have their own view
    // url will be nested (/form/profile)
    .state('form.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'templates/campaignForm/form-profile.html'
    })

    // url will be /form/interests
    .state('form.interests', {
        url: '/interests',
        templateUrl: 'templates/campaignForm/form-interests.html'
    })

    // url will be /form/payment
    .state('form.payment', {
        url: '/payment',
        templateUrl: 'templates/campaignForm/form-payment.html'
    })


// catch all route
// send users to the form page 
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/profile');
})

// our controller for the form
// =============================================================================
.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {

// we will store all of our form data in this object
$scope.formData = {};
 $scope.test = "FUNCIONA";
// function to process the form
$scope.processForm = function() {
    alert('awesome!');  
};

 });
```

But to make this form work I need to use `<div ui-view></div>` and when I put this on my file nothing happens, and I think it's because the app is using my main module "bionico" $stateProvider configurations and not "bionico.formApp"

Here is my html code:

```
        <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
                <!-- views will be injected here -->
             <div ui-view></div>

             {{test}}
```

the {{test}} from formCtrl works fine, it is printing the variable on my screen, but like I said ui-view is not. Is there a way to tell angular that I want to use "bionico.formApp" configurations and not the configs from my main module?
How would you solve this?

Like I think I have to tell angular that from that moment on I want to use "bionico.formApp" but I don't know how to do it.
I've tried 
`<div ng-app="bionico.formApp">` but nothing happened, not even errors

I saw then on stack over flow that I have to bootstrap it manually, but then I got an error saying that "bionico.formApp" had already been bootstraped

### Update

People suggested that I only needed to rout stuff in only one module, but I needed two different default routs one for my main application and one or my form, but that wouldn't work. 
and the reason why I was trying to make this work was because I needed a step by step form (wizard) on my application like this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router)

But I've decided it is not worth the hassle, I'll try to find another wizard for angular js

I'm using now this walktrough wizard:
https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard

It was easy to install and it is very easy to customize the template, I recommend!

Comment: I don't have an example with 2 modules using the `ui.router` but I have an example with several modules all being used with one using `ui.router`. maybe it will give you an idea of how to integrate modules check it [here](https://github.com/joeLloyd/DoingAngularRight)

Comment: wait... two modules? what??? why??? using UI-router just create a base for the form. and make it absolute... and then create a flow which inherits said base... its really no different from any other flow... and there is NO need to create a separated module for it... use your regular app ui-router... add a new flow base and all and just work with that...

Comment: @Jony-Y using multiple modules is not uncommon and neither is it a problem

Comment: just inject ui-router once in main app module, not in `child` modules and only ever have one `otherwise`

Comment: @Jony-Y the thing is that i need to have two different defaults routs
This one for the form:
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/profile');

But for my application there is another default route

Comment: Well i'll try putting everything in the main app and check what happens, maybe i'm imgining stuff here
thanks

Comment: @MichelleColin you really don't need a separate module just for routing, but it should work nonetheless if you do have separate ones. The whole app can only have one default route though

Comment: @charlietfl , there are certain things you might want to use multiple modules... routing does not seem to me like one of them.... when I said why, of course I meant for the routing issue... so... again... never saw two modules used in routing....

Comment: @Jony-Y there are some yoeman seed apps that use a new module for every feature and each module includes a config block for routes associated with that module

Comment: @charlietfl come to think about it, sounds more modular... ok... I can see your point... I guess you might possibly be on a certain level to an extent somewhat correct ... :)

Comment: @MichelleColin so which step-by-step (wizard) you ended up with?

Comment: @rahul I've decided to use this one: https://github.com/mgonto/angular-wizard